# How to serve user uploaded media files in Django Production without any using anything else as a service?

Tags: django, static, media, whitenoise

What is the best way to serve media files in Production without using S3 or FTP?

Whitenoise doesn't support it. I'll have to serve some ZIP files that'll be created from a view.

I can compromise security aspects, will run it on RailwayApp.

I had tried using Whitenoise but it doesn't support media files.

Comment: Django is not made to server media files in a production environment, but there are ways to serve these files from you own webserver. Please share more information on how you are running Django. Are you using a webserver running NGINX/Apache? Heroku or DigitalOcean? Something else?

Comment: I am currently hosting on CPanel. Everything works when Debug = False; even static files. But cannot access media files :'(
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^media/(.*)$ /home/ventureb/buccpanel/media/$1 [L]

<Directory /home/ventureb/buccpanel>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/')`